# I need a javascript code to count how many time the first letter of several <td> appears

Tags: javascript, math, counting

I want to count how many times my team won or lost (V or D) in each competition (LSB or TUC or JUCS) and then display those results separated by results AND competition in other table with the ID table_resultados_gerais.

I've tried it for so long  to isolate the first letter to make this math but I could't accomplish what I want properly, can someone help me?

```
<html>

<body>

    <div id="div_resultados_gerais">
        <table id="table_resultados_gerais">
            <tbody>
                <thead>
                    <th colspan="3">Total</th>
                    <th colspan="3">JUCS</th>
                    <th colspan="3">LSB</th>
                    <th colspan="3">TUC</th>
                </thead>

                <tr>
                    <!-- TOTAL -->
                    <td class="d">10</td>
                    <td class="separador">-</td>
                    <td class="e">7</td>

                    <!-- JUCS -->
                    <td class="d">v</td>
                    <td class="separador">-</td>
                    <td class="e">d</td>

                    <!-- LSB -->
                    <td class="d">5</td>
                    <td class="separador">-</td>
                    <td class="e">6</td>

                    <!-- TUC -->
                    <td class="d">5</td>
                    <td class="separador">-</td>
                    <td class="e">1</td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>


    <div id="div_calendario_jogos">
        <table id="table_calendario_jogos">
            <tbody>
                <tr id="table_header">
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Time</th>
                    <th>Season</th>
                    <th colspan="2">Oponente</th>
                    <th>Placar</th>
                    <th>Competition</th>
                </tr>
            </tbody>

            <tbody class="tbody_calendario_jogos">
                <tr>
                    <td>11/03/2018</td>
                    <td>15:00h</td>
                    <td>Regular</td>
                    <td>BMC</td>
                    <td>V, 52-42</td>
                    <td>LSB</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>08/04/2018</td>
                    <td>12:30h</td>
                    <td>Regular</td>
                    <td>Drink Team</td>
                    <td>D, 59-61</td>
                    <td>LSB</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>22/04/2018</td>
                    <td>10:30h</td>
                    <td>Regular</td>
                    <td>Nitcheroy Ballers</td>
                    <td>V, 53-40</td>
                    <td>TUC</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>28/04/2018</td>
                    <td>12:00h</td>
                    <td>Regular</td>
                    <td>Nacional</td>
                    <td>V, 50-34</td>
                    <td>LSB</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>06/05/2018</td>
                    <td>14:00h</td>
                    <td>Regular</td>
                    <td>VR Ballers</td>
                    <td>D, 45-74</td>
                    <td>LSB</td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td>11/03/2018</td>
                    <td>15:00h</td>
                    <td>Regular</td>
                    <td>BMC</td>
                    <td>V, 52-42</td>
                    <td>TUC</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>08/04/2018</td>
                    <td>12:30h</td>
                    <td>Regular</td>
                    <td>Drink Team</td>
                    <td>D, 59-61</td>
                    <td>LSB</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>22/04/2018</td>
                    <td>10:30h</td>
                    <td>Regular</td>
                    <td>Nitcheroy Ballers</td>
                    <td>V, 53-40</td>
                    <td>TUC</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>28/04/2018</td>
                    <td>12:00h</td>
                    <td>Regular</td>
                    <td>Nacional</td>
                    <td>V, 50-34</td>
                    <td>JUCS</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>06/05/2018</td>
                    <td>14:00h</td>
                    <td>Regular</td>
                    <td>VR Ballers</td>
                    <td>D, 45-74</td>
                    <td>JUCS</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
var res = {
  "JUCS": {
    "V": 0,
    "D": 0
  },

  "LSB": {
    "V": 0,
    "D": 0
  },
  "TUC": {
    "V": 0,
    "D": 0
  },
}
document.querySelectorAll("table td:nth-of-type(5)").forEach(function(cell) {
  var text = cell.textContent;
  var vd = text.split(",")[0];
  var team = cell.nextElementSibling.textContent;
  if ("VD".indexOf(vd) > -1) res[team][vd]++
});
var v=0, d=0;
for (team in res) {
  var V = res[team]["V"], D = res[team]["D"];
  v += V
  d += D
  document.getElementById(team+"_V").textContent = V;
  document.getElementById(team+"_D").textContent = D;
}
document.getElementById("total_V").textContent = v;
document.getElementById("total_D").textContent = d;
```

```html
<div id="div_resultados_gerais">
  <table id="table_resultados_gerais">
    <thead>
      <th colspan="3">Total</th>
      <th colspan="3">JUCS</th>
      <th colspan="3">LSB</th>
      <th colspan="3">TUC</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tb">
      <tr>
        <!-- TOTAL -->
        <td id="total_V" class="d">10</td>
        <td class="separador">-</td>
        <td id="total_D" class="e">7</td>

        <!-- JUCS -->
        <td id="JUCS_V" class="d">v</td>
        <td class="separador">-</td>
        <td id="JUCS_D" class="e">d</td>

        <!-- LSB -->
        <td id="LSB_V" class="d">5</td>
        <td class="separador">-</td>
        <td id="LSB_D" class="e">6</td>

        <!-- TUC -->
        <td id="TUC_V" class="d">5</td>
        <td class="separador">-</td>
        <td id="TUC_D" class="e">1</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>


<div id="div_calendario_jogos">
  <table id="table_calendario_jogos">
    <tbody>
      <tr id="table_header">
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Season</th>
        <th colspan="2">Oponente</th>
        <th>Placar</th>
        <th>Competition</th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tbody class="tbody_calendario_jogos">
      <tr>
        <td>11/03/2018</td>
        <td>15:00h</td>
        <td>Regular</td>
        <td>BMC</td>
        <td>V, 52-42</td>
        <td>LSB</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>08/04/2018</td>
        <td>12:30h</td>
        <td>Regular</td>
        <td>Drink Team</td>
        <td>D, 59-61</td>
        <td>LSB</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>22/04/2018</td>
        <td>10:30h</td>
        <td>Regular</td>
        <td>Nitcheroy Ballers</td>
        <td>V, 53-40</td>
        <td>TUC</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>28/04/2018</td>
        <td>12:00h</td>
        <td>Regular</td>
        <td>Nacional</td>
        <td>V, 50-34</td>
        <td>LSB</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>06/05/2018</td>
        <td>14:00h</td>
        <td>Regular</td>
        <td>VR Ballers</td>
        <td>D, 45-74</td>
        <td>LSB</td>
      </tr>


      <tr>
        <td>11/03/2018</td>
        <td>15:00h</td>
        <td>Regular</td>
        <td>BMC</td>
        <td>V, 52-42</td>
        <td>TUC</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>08/04/2018</td>
        <td>12:30h</td>
        <td>Regular</td>
        <td>Drink Team</td>
        <td>D, 59-61</td>
        <td>LSB</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>22/04/2018</td>
        <td>10:30h</td>
        <td>Regular</td>
        <td>Nitcheroy Ballers</td>
        <td>V, 53-40</td>
        <td>TUC</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>28/04/2018</td>
        <td>12:00h</td>
        <td>Regular</td>
        <td>Nacional</td>
        <td>V, 50-34</td>
        <td>JUCS</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>06/05/2018</td>
        <td>14:00h</td>
        <td>Regular</td>
        <td>VR Ballers</td>
        <td>D, 45-74</td>
        <td>JUCS</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: yeaahh, but how can I replace the content inside those <td class="d"> and <td class="e">??

Comment: With what exactly?

Comment: with the sum of each competition

Comment: for example, on tuc' <td> i have a 5 for wins and 1 for loses. i wanna replace those values for 3 and 0 respectively, once this is the sum of them

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you expect a result like this

```
{
    "LSB": {
        "V": 2,
        "D": 3
    },
    "TUC": {
        "V": 3
    },
    "JUCS": {
        "V": 1,
        "D": 1
    }
}
```

Which you will later turn into a table

You can try the following

```js
const table = document.querySelector('#table_calendario_jogos');
    const rows = [...table.tBodies[0].rows];
    const dataset = rows.map(row => {
        const cells = [...row.cells];
        const object = {};

        object.placar = cells[4].textContent[0];
        object.competition = cells[5].textContent;

        return object
    });

    const result = dataset.reduce((accumulator, currentValue, index, array) => {
        if (!accumulator[currentValue.competition]) {
            accumulator[currentValue.competition] = array
                .filter(item => item.competition === currentValue.competition)
                .map(item => item.placar)
                .reduce((acc, val) => {
                    if (!acc[val]) {
                        acc[val] = 1;
                    } else {
                        acc[val] = acc[val] + 1;
                    }

                    return acc;
                }, {});
        }

        return accumulator;
    }, {});

    console.log(result);

    // Render result table
    const t = document.createElement('table');
    const thead = document.createElement('thead');
    const tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
    const th1 = document.createElement('th');
    const th2 = document.createElement('th');
    const th3 = document.createElement('th');

    th1.textContent = 'Placar';
    th2.textContent = 'V';
    th3.textContent = 'D';

    thead.appendChild(th1);
    thead.appendChild(th2);
    thead.appendChild(th3);

    t.appendChild(thead);

    for (const key in result) {
        const tr = document.createElement('tr');
        const td1 = document.createElement('td');
        const td2 = document.createElement('td');
        const td3 = document.createElement('td');

        td1.textContent = key;
        td2.textContent = result[key].V;
        td3.textContent = result[key].D;

        tr.appendChild(td1);
        tr.appendChild(td2);
        tr.appendChild(td3);

        tbody.appendChild(tr)

        t.appendChild(tbody);
    }

document.querySelector('#result').appendChild(t);
```

```html
<div id="div_resultados_gerais">
    <table id="table_resultados_gerais">
        <tbody>
            <thead>
                <th colspan="3">Total</th>
                <th colspan="3">JUCS</th>
                <th colspan="3">LSB</th>
                <th colspan="3">TUC</th>
            </thead>

            <tr>
                <!-- TOTAL -->
                <td class="d">10</td>
                <td class="separador">-</td>
                <td class="e">7</td>

                <!-- JUCS -->
                <td class="d">v</td>
                <td class="separador">-</td>
                <td class="e">d</td>

                <!-- LSB -->
                <td class="d">5</td>
                <td class="separador">-</td>
                <td class="e">6</td>

                <!-- TUC -->
                <td class="d">5</td>
                <td class="separador">-</td>
                <td class="e">1</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<div id="result"></div>

<div id="div_calendario_jogos">
    <table id="table_calendario_jogos">
        <thead>
            <tr id="table_header">
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Time</th>
                <th>Season</th>
                <th colspan="2">Oponente</th>
                <th>Placar</th>
                <th>Competition</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody class="tbody_calendario_jogos">
            <tr>
                <td>11/03/2018</td>
                <td>15:00h</td>
                <td>Regular</td>
                <td>BMC</td>
                <td>V, 52-42</td>
                <td>LSB</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>08/04/2018</td>
                <td>12:30h</td>
                <td>Regular</td>
                <td>Drink Team</td>
                <td>D, 59-61</td>
                <td>LSB</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>22/04/2018</td>
                <td>10:30h</td>
                <td>Regular</td>
                <td>Nitcheroy Ballers</td>
                <td>V, 53-40</td>
                <td>TUC</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>28/04/2018</td>
                <td>12:00h</td>
                <td>Regular</td>
                <td>Nacional</td>
                <td>V, 50-34</td>
                <td>LSB</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>06/05/2018</td>
                <td>14:00h</td>
                <td>Regular</td>
                <td>VR Ballers</td>
                <td>D, 45-74</td>
                <td>LSB</td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>11/03/2018</td>
                <td>15:00h</td>
                <td>Regular</td>
                <td>BMC</td>
                <td>V, 52-42</td>
                <td>TUC</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>08/04/2018</td>
                <td>12:30h</td>
                <td>Regular</td>
                <td>Drink Team</td>
                <td>D, 59-61</td>
                <td>LSB</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>22/04/2018</td>
                <td>10:30h</td>
                <td>Regular</td>
                <td>Nitcheroy Ballers</td>
                <td>V, 53-40</td>
                <td>TUC</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>28/04/2018</td>
                <td>12:00h</td>
                <td>Regular</td>
                <td>Nacional</td>
                <td>V, 50-34</td>
                <td>JUCS</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>06/05/2018</td>
                <td>14:00h</td>
                <td>Regular</td>
                <td>VR Ballers</td>
                <td>D, 45-74</td>
                <td>JUCS</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```